# Authentication methods for Zend Framework XML-RPC server

Tags: php, zend-framework, xml-rpc

I have a Zend Framework application whose sole purpose is to serve as an XmlRpc / JSONRPC server.

I've mostly followed the philosophy from [this guide](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/227-Exposing-Service-APIs-via-Zend-Framework.html) for my implementation method. I overrode my Bootstrap's run() method to run a Zend_XmlRpc_Server object and attach the API classes to it.

I want to authenticate any XML-RPC method that gets ran with an "API key" I have stored in a database table. If I had a traditional MVC ZF setup, I would use a controller plugin to automatically take care of the authentication, but I don't have that option. My only solution right now is manually insert code into each API method to check for authentication.

Any thoughts on a more pragmatic way to solve this issue? I'd prefer not to have a bunch of repeated code at the top of every method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

several ways to solve the q

1. easiest create in Bootstrap Reqest Object manually and check headers

   ```
   protected function _initModifiedFrontController()
   {
       $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
       $front = $this->getResource('FrontController');

       $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();

       $response = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http();
       $response->setHeader('Content-Type','text/html; charset=UTF-8', true);
       $front->setResponse($response);
       $front->setRequest($request);

       if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
           $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
               $dbAdapter,
               'users',
               'username',
               'password'
           );

           // ...or configure the instance with setter methods
           $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbAdapter);

           $authAdapter
               ->setTableName('users')
               ->setIdentityColumn('username')
               ->setCredentialColumn('password')
           ;

       }
   }
   ```

Read manual Zend_Auth. this is a "zend way".

or u can write custom AuthAdaper.it's easy :)

UPDATE 1:

[Read this carefully](http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/architecting-ajax-applications-with-zend-framework)

Comment: Thanks - I didn't quite use the frontcontroller method you used, but it got me thinking in the right direction. Your link was also very useful. Thank you.